# How can I remove pimples on my face?

Tags: health

How can I remove pimples on my face? 
Sometimes these pimples clearly appear on my face.So I can't makeup on any event. You can tell me how can remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice to have more information about your problem. Do you have them how often? They're inflamed bumps or white heads? Either way, I suggest you to find a dermatologist. It's the only way you can discover the source of your skin condition. Until then I can give you some advice on skin care:

> Previous Care: You need to care for your skin even if it's not affected by acne on that moment.

HYDRATE YOUR SKIN: Even if you have oily skin, it's important to moisturizer your skin. You need to choose the best product for your skin type and sometimes you'll need even more than one. For example: you can have oily skin on your forehead and dry skin on your cheeks, in that case, you need to use two different moisturizer to get a better result. Hydrating your skin will improve skin elasticity, prevent lesions and improve appearance. Drinking water is also a great factor and will help your skin clear out if you're already experiencing pimples and acne.

SUN PROTECTION: Use sunscreen even if you're not going to leave the house. The sun is a good helper to kill bacteria that are on top of your skin but long time exposure can cause damage and will make your skin more prone to inflamed acne. Choose your sunscreen according with your skin type and try to apply it everyday.

DON'T TOUCH: I don't know if this is your situation, but picking at a pimple does not go well with healing it. Try to not touch your face with your fingers during the day and try to keep your hands as clean as possible. Don't pop your pimples! If you have hair touching your face, like bangs or so, try to use them tied with a hairgrip away from your skin. If you have pimples near your hair roots maybe you should increase the number of hair washes per week.

MAKEUP: If you use makeup on a daily basis, it's essential to wash it all off on the end of the day. Use a face-only soap and cloth. It's hard to accept it but you shouldn't use makeup on top of your acne or inflamed pimples. There's makeup made for this purpose, but cream-based makeup should be away from pimples.

> Breakout: When the pimples are red and inflamed. Don't pop them! Bacteria from your fingernails and even the ones that live on top of your skin may enter your organism when you squeeze pimples. Try to not touch them and use some anti-acne gel to dry the pimple. These kind of products can be recommended by a dermatologist. If the area is too painful and inflamed, you can apply a cold compress directly on the affected area.
>
> Aftermath: To decrease scarring, don't pick the scars or the affected area. Protect the skin from the sun so It doesn't get darker. Get in touch with a dermatologist to see what you can do about acne scars.
>
> Skin conditions as health indicators: Sometimes pimples can mean other health issues so it's important that you seek medical advice. Acne can be caused by hormonal changes, skin conditions, food intolerance, etc.

Comment: Yes , Have some white heads as well as some black head on my face.

Answer (score -2):

Take one piece of garlic and rub it on pimples for two minutes then you will see the 50 % result in just two minutes.